# sh: vite: command not found Error: Command "vite build" exited with 127

Tags: reactjs, vite

I am new to stackoverFlow .
When i try to deploy my vite(react) project on vercel im getting sh: vite: command not found
Error: Command "vite build" exited with 127.

i have tried npm i,and also watched youtube videos none of them solved my problems

Comment: Did you try to deleted the `node_modules` folder and `package-json.lock `and 
`npm install` again